# Is System.Drawing supported in xamarin.android 8 and above?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, system.drawing

I need to use System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Common in my Xamarin.Android project but it can't load System.Drawing.Common.dll.

As I know xamarin.android 8.0 and above are .net standard 2.0 compatible, then it should work out-of-the-box. I have read that there's no way to use these libraries in xamarin.android, but these articles where made before xamarin.android 8.0 was published.

Thanks for your answers

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1590,2): error : Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1590,2): error : Nazwa pliku: 'System.Drawing.Common.dll'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1590,2): error :    w Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1590,2): error :    w Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1590,2): error :    w Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)
```

**Update**

I have found [that](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28886) on the web.
Maybe it is the problem here. Then, where i can find this .dll?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is supported, but NuGet package for System.Drawing.Common isn't builded in the right way for MonoAndroid.